# Creating a mosaic from multiple Landsat scenes on Qgis

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, image, landsat

I wish to produce a large image. As a base use cloud free regions of multiple Landsat images. I wish to keep the bands and be able to work with the generated mosaic just like a "normal" Landsat image.
What ways would you propose to archive a satisfying result?
I am on Linux/Qgis

Comment: Are trying to mask the clouds or do you want to create a cloud free mosaic from multiple scenes for the same location?

Comment: Exactly , i wish to crate a cloud free mosaic from multiple scenes for one large region.

Answer (score 1):

You can also build a virtual raster file (vrt) with GDAL

Add all tif in folder to vrt

```
gdalbuildvrt C:/tifs/my_vrt C:/tifs/*.tif
```

Build a pyramid for increased performance

```
gdaladdo -r AVERAGE --config BIGTIFF_OVERVIEW=YES -ro --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW DEFLATE --config PREDICTOR_OVERVIEW 2 --config ZLEVEL 9 C:/tifs/my_vrt.vrt 2 4 8 16 32 64
```

You can use the GDAL VRT builder from QGIS menu Raster > Miscellaneous > Build Virtual Raster Catalog ... You can also make pyramids from the same Miscellaneous menu.

Comment: i very appreciate your answer but isn't there a way without using GDAL? This exceeds my knowledge of GIS by far.

Comment: You can use the GDAL VRT builder from QGIS menu Raster > Miscellaneous > Build Virtual Raster Catalog ... You can also make pyramids from the same Miscellaneous menu.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the gdal library outside Qgis

[Gdal merge](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html)

ps : If your outpout tiff is more than 4g make sure to add the BigTiff option

[co options](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html)

Comment: I have to cut large parts of the base images because they overly each other. is this possible in Gdal? i have never worked with it before

Comment: with gdalwarp you can apply clipping yes